# Facebook Linter picks up og:tags, Facebook itself does not

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a very simple test page at http://student.cqu.edu.au/s0147794/. 
It has an og:url in its header that redirects to http://student.cqu.edu.au/s0147794/next.html, which has og:title, og:description and og:url properties.  I run the first link through Linter, and all looks good. There are no errors or warnings, and I can see my properties being recognised as below.

> og:url `http://student.cqu.edu.au/s0147794/next.html
>   og:type     website
>   og:title    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>   og:description  DO NOT Ignore this one
>   og:updated_time 1329102748

However, when I actually click the Like button, and post to my facebook wall...

> My Name liked a Link. 12 seconds ago 
>   **<-- Title should be here** 
>   `http://student.cqu.edu.au/s0147794/next.html **<-- Correct URL** 
>  
>   student.cqu.edu.au **<-- This should be the description** 
>   Like · · Share

All I get is a link to the page, and a link to the domain underneath it, where the description should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place all og meta tags on the same page so it will start working fine.

Place them in header as defined in [like plugin in api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.site.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.simplyzesty.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Facebook-logo.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="You User ID" />
```

Comment: I'll try it out, the page does say they're all required, but if that's the case, why didn't Lint tell me?  And I'm sure I had something similar working before with only a few of them.